# How to disable a button efficiently and only show a message?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a view controller called `LevelViewController` I inserted onto it buttons that represent levels from one to four. When player clicks on the level button it segues it to view controller called `GameViewController` in 'Model Way' with "Level Number" identifier. Though the player must reach a specific score in order to unlock the other button and allow the buttons perform segue to the `GameViewController` with an identifier (the score data is saved on `NSUserDefault` object).

So far what I came up with is to disable the buttons through Xcode and Enable them programmatically once the player reached the wanted score.
The foregoing solution is easy and may save me time but I really think it doesn't give much details for the consumer as well as it is not clickable which means I can't show an alert view window explaining the message. So I thought perhaps anyone can give me further ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use a custom button whose disabled image is a red X or some such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To let the user know that the other buttons exist but are currently disabled, set the button's alpha to 0.5 to fade it. Then you can have a boolean that indicates whether the button is disabled.
Then in each button's callback, if the boolean is set to indicate disabled, show a message, else do the normal button action.

```
// level1Button and level2Button are UIButton IBOutlets... 
// Let level 2 be disabled

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    level2Button.alpha = 0.5;
    level1Enabled = TRUE;
    level2Enabled = FALSE;

    [super viewDidLoad];
}


- (IBAction) level1Button:(id)sender {
    if (level1Enabled) {
        // Go to level 1...
    } else {
        // Show alert...
    }
}

- (IBAction) level2Button:(id)sender {
    if (level2Enabled) {
        // Go to level 1...
    } else {
        // Show alert...
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the response ,regarding to setting the alpha to 0.5 is unnecessary when you you disable a button on Xcode it automatically makes it transparent and as I mentioned earlier when you disable button 2 it won't be clickable.

Comment: From what I understand you need the button to still be clickable to show an alert when it is disabled. Therefore I suggested changing the alpha so that the button is still clickable (disabling programatically  will make it non-clickable) and showing an alert to notify the user that the level is currently locked. HTH